# Why the same version of Firebase in pub.dev generates a different SDK?

Tags: flutter, firebase

I have two apps with the same pub.dev version in pubspec.yaml:

```
  firebase_analytics: ^9.3.8 
  firebase_core: ^1.8.0 
  firebase_database: ^8.2.0 
  firebase_auth: ^3.1.4 
  firebase_messaging: ^11.1.0
```

Both work fine on IOS and Android, but one of them doesn't compile for Web. The difference I see is that at the time of the dependency analysis, the one that compiles fine uses Firebase SDK version '9.5.0' defined in 'firebase_core' and the other uses version 9.6.0.

The one that works badly generates an error when compiling of the type:

```
Error: Error when reading '../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_core-1.24.0/lib/src/internals.dart': No such file or directory
internals.dart:2
export 'package:firebase_core/src/internals.dart' hide guardWebExceptions;
```

Why if the firebase_core from pub.dev is the same (1.8.0), are they both based on different versions?

How can I downgrade from version 9.6.0 to version 9.5.0 of the Firebase SDK while maintaining integrity?